# How can I use a Responsive design in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, responsive-design

Is there a possibility to implement a responsive design for shiny apps? In the browser my app looks good and it can be used as intended. If I try to use it on a smartphone or a tablet it isn't usable without lots of scrolling.

Can I make my app responsive for different devices?

Thx and greetings
Derlu

Comment: Please provide more information on what you have done in order for us to better answer your question. Shiny layout are responsive and especially fluidPage.

Answer (score 2):

Shiny is built upon Bootstrap which is able to factor in some device constraints such as using percentages as opposed to pixel values for width and height values of elements.

If you need further control over what is shown, I suggest either using a package like [shinyMobile](https://rinterface.github.io/shinyMobile/) or by using a browser ready layout system such as [flexboxes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_responsive.asp). Alternatively, you can use the [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) package which is built so that "Components are intelligently re-sized to fill the browser and adapted for display on mobile devices." (from their website, although I have not personally used it to vouch for its ease of use)

If you want to really customize the experience and design two separate views for desktop and mobile, then you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820481/r-shiny-app-detect-mobile) on how to distinguish device size.

I hope this helps, William