# Do not load element of Rmd page if user is on mobile

Tags: r, mobile, shiny, r-markdown, quarto

I have an Rmd report which contains a large asset (in the form of a leaflet map htmlwidget) that I do not want to be loaded if the viewer is on mobile. Is there a way to do this?
I am aware of using css media queries but that will prevent an item from being *displayed*, but it doesn't prevent it from being ***loaded*** which is what I'm going for here.

I have found some recommendations for a similar case using img and lazy loading, but I don't believe that is applicable here.

I can see a somewhat hacky way of achieving this using shiny::renderUI and jquery passing a message back to shiny with the window's width, but would prefer to do it entirely in rmarkdown or if there is a more elegant way.

Thanks

Edit:

I have included a reprex below that shows the issue I would like to solve

````
---
title: "no load on mobile reprex"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

library(htmltools)
library(leaflet)
library(spData)

# In practice, this would be a large map object of several MBs that we don't 
#   want the viewer to see *or even to load* if they are on mobile
mapdata = us_states
```

```{js}
// For simplicity, let's just use the case of a small window width
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    console.log('window_width is ',window_width);
});
```

```{css}
/* 
This CSS will hide the map when the screen is small, but it has 2 issues.
    1. it will dynamically reevaluate when the window size, whereas I would only like one check on page load
    2. if you look at the network tab, the map still gets loaded, which is a waste of bandwidth for mobile users
*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #desktopOnlyContent {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

## A message to all users

```{r}
h3('This message is for all users')
```

## Different content for different users

```{r}
div(id = 'desktopOnlyContent',
    h3('If you can see this, that means you have a large screen'),
        p('If you dont have a large screen then this should not even be visible in the elements tab of the devtools inside your browser, because if it is, then it is wasting bandwidth'),
        leaflet(elementId = 'desktopMap') |> 
            addPolygons(data = mapdata)
)
```

## Another message to all users

```{r}
h3('This message is also for all users')
```
````

Comment: Is this about a `Rmd` using shiny-runtime or a `shiny` app rendering a `Rmd` file? Please share some code so we can see the structureof your project.

Comment: About pure Rmd, but if that's not possible I was hoping there was an easier way to achieve it in a prerendered_shiny Rmd without using jQuery and to message the shiny process about whether a mobile was being used or not. I have also looked at the shinybrowser package, but that didn't work well in my prerendered_shiny document. To reiterate though, I am looking for a pure Rmd solution

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment: you should have (and you still should) provided example code to make that clear.

Comment: Hi, I added a reprex in the original post. Hopefully that clears it up a bit. Please let me know if not

Comment: Added my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73125721/9841389).